# angular-calender and date-fns failed to compile in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular-7 application want to install angular-calender, so I ran this:

> npm install --save angular-calendar date-fns

I went through the documentation and added the code below:

```
/* angular-cli file: src/styles.css */
@import "../node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css";
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot({
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory
    })
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

When I ran

> ng serve --o

I expected the application to compile but I got this error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

`angular-calendar` dependency of `date-fns` is fixed to `1.30.x` while the latest `date-fns` version is on `2.x.x`. That might be the reason it's not able to resolve. Try installing the suggested version of date-fns using `npm i date-fns@1.30.1`.